# How to get client remote ip address in resource controller

Tags: dart, aqueduct

How can I access request.connectioninfo.remoteaddress in a function of a resourcecontroller? I need to store and log the client remote IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the raw property of the request https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/aqueduct/latest/aqueduct/Request/raw.html

Edit by CA:
The request object is already present in a controller that extends from ResourceController or Controller and can simply be used as such:

```
final remote_address = request.raw.connectionInfo.remoteAddress.address;
```

Comment: Ok, so I understood that I can create a middleware controller, override the handle function, use request.raw.connectionInfo() to get the remote IP, and attach it to request.attachments. But how can I access the request.attachments properties in the subsequent resource controller function annotated by @Operation.post? Can I somehow bind to it through @Bind annotation?

Answer (score -1):

You can’t bind it, but you access it the same way. The request is available as a property of a resource controller, so it’s available in every method.

Comment: Ok, got it. as I'm extending from Controller, the handle method is executed which has the request, I can use it as such in my controller directly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It was meant as a comment to the other answer if you can move it